# What are these red dots on the UV vertices?

Tags: uv

Red dots appeared on UV vertices, what are these and how do I get rid of them?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are pin vertices, it allows you to keep these vertices at these positions if you choose to <kbd>U</kbd> > *Unwrap* again. To pin, select the vertices you want and <kbd>P</kbd>. To unpin, select and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>

Comment: That both solved the problem and taught me something very useful, thanks.